# Crop and Resize image with percentage width and height

Tags: html, css, image

I want to make a article preview, as you can see on nearly every shopsite.

[image]

My problem is the image inside the divs. The page should be responsive, that why the width and height of the divs are a percentage value. My question is now, how can I crop and center the image inside the divs?

Here is my code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}

.articlePreview{
    display: inline-block;
    
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    
    max-width: 15%;
    max-height: 15%;
    
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="articlePreview">
                <div class="imgPreview">
                    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200"/>
                </div>
                
                <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="articlePreview">
                <div class="imgPreview">
                    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/500"/>
                </div>
                
                <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="articlePreview">
                <div class="imgPreview">
                    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
                </div>
                
                <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each image the same height correspondent to the size of the viewing window. E.g. 10vh etc. in your css. This way all the images will remain the same height dependent upon the size of the window. You are using the classes you are setting on the divs but not the images themselves. If you use the class you added to the images you can specify the height, padding, etc.

For instance...

```
.img {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
}
```

Now they all have the same size. It will distort the images if they are not square to begin with. It is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body, html
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.articlePreview{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    height:15%;
    
    max-width: 15%;
    max-height:15%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    
    background-color: orange;
}
.imgPreview
{
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
}
.img
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.imgTitle
{
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="articlePreview">
                <div class="imgPreview">
                    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200"/>
                </div>
                <div class="imgTitle">
                  <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="articlePreview">
                <div class="imgPreview">
                    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/500"/>
                </div>
                <div class="imgTitle">
                  <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="articlePreview">
                <div class="imgPreview">
                    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
                </div>
                <div class="imgTitle">
                  <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```